# Inheritance from two abstract classes

Tags: c++

I have a problem that I have not yet tested/compiled and wondering if it is possible and if it is bad design?

My Problem:

I want to have an abstract base class A and a abstract derived class B.

I realize if this is possible I will have a number of pure virtual member functions in each class and also I will not be able to initialize these objects, but that is a given for abstract classes.

In my design I will have another derived class C which I would then initialize - class C would be derived from class B.

I would have something that looked like this

```
class C
  ^
  |
abstract class B
  ^
  |
abstract base class A
```

My Question:

Is this possible first of all? I would suspect so, but not declaring the pure virtual functions in A in class B may be troublesome?

e.x.

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual void test()=0;
 };

class B: public A {
  public:
   virtual void test()=0;
   virtual void anotherTest()=0;
 };
```

Is the above okay?

Is this bad c++ design? In future I will have derived classes from A so it would be nice to have this design.

Comment: Regarding the "is it possible?" question: what are you waiting for to try compiling it? Regarding the "is it bad design?" question: we can't really tell that without knowing the requirements of what you are designing.

Comment: Yes, its fine. Why would this be bad design? e.g. Animal, and its descendant Mammal are both abstract, but are good bases for further concrete classes.

Comment: I have not finished writing it. :-D plus I wanted to consider if I was over doing the abstract class design.

Comment: Instead of writing the whole shebang, you can just write a small prototype (I think I could do that in less than 20 lines) that tests the parts you're not sure about.

Comment: [works fine](http://ideone.com/ebXJS)

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes good point!! Doh

Comment: @nonb yes with your example I can see that my design fits in with this philosophy. If you want to call it that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it, and it will certainly work. Example follows

```
stefanos-imac:dftb borini$ more test.cpp 
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    A(void) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; } 

    virtual void method1() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(void) : A() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }

    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C(void) : B() { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }

    virtual void method1() { std::cout << "method1" << std::endl; }
    virtual void method2() {std::cout << "method2" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.method1();
    c.method2();
}
stefanos-imac:dftb borini$ ./a.out 
A
B
C
method1
method2
```

Thank you for reminding me that I can still type basic C++.

Comment: Just what I wanted to see - next time I will test it myself before asking a question! Cheers Stefano!

Comment: @MWright: Normally we downvote for questions that "show no research effort", but we spared you due to you being new to the site.